# Delete custom UITableViewCell when checkbox is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am a student trying to learn iOS programming and have run into some trouble. I am trying to add a checkbox button to my custom UITableViewCell and allow it to delete the cell when pressed. However, even though I can add the button and it can be pressed, nothing happens. The UITableViewCell is still there. How can I fix this?

This is my custom cell class:

```
import UIKit

class ClientCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var clientImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func checkBoxTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.isSelected == true {
            sender.isSelected = false
        } else {
            sender.isSelected = true
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ViewController that contains the UITableView:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ClientsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Client")
    var clients = [NSManagedObject]()

    @IBOutlet weak var clientTable: UITableView!

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return clients.count
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ClientCell
        cell.label.text = clients[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "name") as? String
        cell.clientImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return(cell)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            CDHandler.deleteObject(indexPath: indexPath)
            clients.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            clientTable.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        if CDHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
            clients = CDHandler.fetchObject()!
        }
        clientTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: commitediting style is different. This will not delete the row, if you want to delete the row when tapping on checkbox(your custom button). you have to setup a delegate between your cell and view controller class and then in your viewcontroller class, you have to use - (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation; along updating your datasource.

Comment: @Deepika thank you for your reply.  The commitediting style function allows me to swipe to delete the cell and data within. This would be if I wanted to completely delete the record from the app. The checkbox is essentially going to reorder the table based on a sorting method I’ll implement later. How would I setup a delegate between the cell and view controller classes?

Comment: this link will help you understand how to setup a delegate between your controller and cell. https://medium.com/@aapierce0/swift-using-protocols-to-add-custom-behavior-to-a-uitableviewcell-2c1f09610aa1

Comment: @Deepika ok thanks! I’ll give it a read!

Comment: @Deepika Thank you! This solved my problem!